# Multiple input linear regression cannot predict outputs of large variance

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, linear-regression

I succeeded to build a linear regression neural network with 1 inputs and 1 outputs.

I am building a linear regression neural network with 5 inputs and 1 outputs now.

Here is the formula:
y = 3e + d^2 + 9c + 11b^6 + a + 19

However, no matter how many neurons, epochs and hidden layers I use, I cannot predict the a good result.
The predicted outputs are always within a small range. However, there are large variance among the expected outputs.
[Predicted output vs Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spt4F.png)

I guess it may be because of the choice of activation function, loss function and optimizer.
If not, multiple input neural network may need alternative method to build.

Here is my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn    #neural network model
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from pickle import dump

#Load datasets
dataset = pd.read_csv('testB_200.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, -1:].values
X_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
print(X_scaler.fit(X))
print(Y_scaler.fit(Y))
X = X_scaler.transform(X)
Y = Y_scaler.transform(Y)

#save the scaler
dump(X_scaler, open('X_scaler.pkl', 'wb'))
dump(Y_scaler, open('Y_scaler.pkl', 'wb'))

train = int((len(dataset)+1)*0.8)
test = train + 1
print(train)
print(test)
x_temp_train = X[:train]
y_temp_train = Y[:train]
x_temp_test = X[test:]
y_temp_test = Y[test:]

X_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_temp_train)
Y_train = torch.FloatTensor(y_temp_train)
X_test = torch.FloatTensor(x_temp_test)
Y_test = torch.FloatTensor(y_temp_test)

D_in = 5 # D_in is input features
H = 12 # H is hidden dimension
H2 =8
H3 =4

D_out = 1 # D_out is output features.

#Define a Artifical Neural Network model
class Net(nn.Module):
#------------------3 hidden Layers------------------------------
    def __init__(self, D_in, H, H2, H3, D_out):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(D_in, H)  
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(H, H2)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(H2, H3)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(H3, D_out)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        #activation function should be used here  e.g: hidden = F.relu(...)
        h_relu = self.linear1(x).clamp(min=0) #min=0 is like ReLU
        middle = self.linear2(h_relu).clamp(min=0)
        middle2 = self.linear3(middle).clamp(min=0)
        prediction = self.linear4(middle2)

        return prediction
model = Net(D_in, H, H2, H3, D_out)
print(model)

#Define a Loss function and optimizer
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.2) #2e-7, lr=learning rate=0.2

#Training model
inputs = Variable(X_train)
outputs = Variable(Y_train)
inputs_val = Variable(X_test)
outputs_val = Variable(Y_test)
loss_values = []
val_values = []
epoch = []
epoch_value=25

for i in range(epoch_value):
    for phase in ['train', 'val']:
        if phase == 'train':
            #print('train loss')
            model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            prediction = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(prediction, outputs) 
            #print(loss)
            loss_values.append(loss.item())
            optimizer.zero_grad() #zero the parameter gradients
            epoch.append(i)
            loss.backward()       #compute gradients(dloss/dx)
            optimizer.step()      #updates the parameters
        elif phase == 'val':
            #print('validation loss')        
            model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode
            prediction_val = model(inputs_val)
            loss_val = criterion(prediction_val, outputs_val) 
            #print(loss_val)
            val_values.append(loss_val.item())
            optimizer.zero_grad() #zero the parameter gradients

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'formula2.pth')  #save model

#Plot train_loss vs validation loss
plt.plot(epoch,loss_values)
plt.plot(epoch, val_values)
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train','validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#plot prediciton vs expected value
prediction_val = prediction_val.detach().numpy()
prediction_val = Y_scaler.inverse_transform(prediction_val)
#print('predict')
#print(prediction_val)
Y_test = Y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y_test)
#print('test')
#print(Y_test)
plt.plot(Y_test)
plt.plot(prediction_val)
plt.legend(['expected','predict'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[Model Loss vs Validation Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWAiC.png)

[Validation vs Expected outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azXNj.png)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're using linear regression with ReLUs in order to predict a high-order polynom? You're going to need a **very** wide hidden layer for that. Or add more layers.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Does a wide hidden layer mean a hidden layer with a lot of neurons?

Comment: Yes. See [Universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)

Comment: The maximum neurons of good fit is H=170, H2=170 and H3=165. However, it did not solve the problem. Moreover, removing all the ReLUs seems to approach the better result.

Comment: Of course. ReLUs are not really suitable for such a task with such a shallow network.